# PHP move_uploaded_file() isn't working

Tags: php, file-upload

It seems a lot of people have had problems with this function. I have quite a few times.
I have changed nothing in the code since it was working about 2 hours ago. 
File permissions are all in order.

The error(s) I get in puTTy are as follows:

```
[Fri Jan 31 21:45:44 2014] [error] [client 87...*removed for obvious reasons*] File does not exist: /home/josh/websites/admin.domain.com/htdocs/upload, referer: http://admin.domain.com/
[Fri Jan 31 21:45:47 2014] [error] [client 87...*removed for obvious reasons*] File does not exist: /home/josh/websites/admin.domain.com/htdocs/[object File], referer: http://domain.com/
```

A simplified version of the move_uploaded_file function is as follows:

```
$fileNameMain = $rand_file_string . "-" . str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"]);
$pathAndName = "../../../../../dev.domain.com/htdocs/southwye/upload/" . $fileNameMain;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"], $pathAndName);
```

What mystifies me the most is the fact that, in the error message, it refers to '/home/josh/websites/domain.com/htdocs/upload' but it is not mentioned at all in the PHP.

I have checked that the PHP variable $pathAndName points to the correct directory by creating a text file there. I just have no idea this time.

Comment: Sounds like a PHP configuration problem. `/home/josh/websites/admin.domain.com/htdocs/upload` is presumably the value of the `upload_tmp_dir` php.ini option.

Comment: My instinct would be that too.  The temp dir may be incorrect, does not have enough space, or no permission to move.  Can you copy instead of move?

Comment: try to upload manualy and check the url in the browser

Comment: I'm not in charge of the server, but I do know that it was reset about a week ago and I think this was the first time I'd attempted a file upload since the reset...so it could be something to do with the comment made by @Barmar. I obviously can't check now as my friend, who manages the server, is probably asleep. In the meantime, could you be a little more specific on what he'd need to change?

Comment: @pc-shooter that's all working fine, it's just the PHP function that's having trouble. Which points even more so to some fault with the php.ini file when using temporary files, as mentioned above.